# How to return value from stored procedure without output parameters

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, return-value

Here's psuedo-code for the stored procedure I currently use,

```
CREATE PROC uspFoo
(
@id int,
@type nvarchar(255),
@status bit output
)
AS
IF ....
SET @status=1
ELSE
SET @status=0
GO
```

When executing this stored procedure, I am forced to pass an output parameter that will store its return value,

```
DECLARE @id int, @type nvarchar(255), @status bit
SET @id=..
SET @type=..
EXEC uspFoo @id, @assayType, @status output

PRINT @status

GO
```

The return value, or in this case `status`, will either be 0 (false) or 1 (true).

How can I return a value (e.g. `bit`) directly without having to store it in a temporary output parameter?

Comment: You might consider [scalar user defined function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175085%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) which you might call from a query, unlike stored procedure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In cases like this you can use the return value from the stored procedure.  The following should work.

```
CREATE PROC uspFoo
(
@id int,
@type nvarchar(255)
)
AS
IF ....
  RETURN 1
ELSE
  RETURN 0
GO
```

To call:

```
DECLARE @id int, @type nvarchar(255), @status bit
SET @id=..
SET @type=..
EXEC @status=uspFoo @id, @assayType

PRINT @status
```