# Retrieving a particular value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this stored procedure that has a value:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @return_value int
    DECLARE @media_id uniqueidentifier

    'INSERT SQL STATEMENT HERE

    SELECT [media_id] FROM [media] WHERE 1 = 1 

    -- One row affected
    RETURN 1
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END

    -- Rollback, no row affected
    RETURN 0
END CATCH;
```

I want to call the [media_id] value from another stored procedure.  How do I get that value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11743655/284111

Comment: added the additional code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Table Definition**

```
CREATE TABLE MY_EMPLOYEE 
(EMPID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20), 
LANGUAGEID INT , ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID())
GO
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_ProcName
@Emp_ID INT = null,
@Name VARCHAR(20) = null,
@LanguageID int =  null,
@NewID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        -- Insert statements for procedure here

       INSERT INTO [Practice_DB].[dbo].[MY_EMPLOYEE](EMPID, NAME, LANGUAGEID)
       VALUES (@Emp_ID, @Name, @LanguageID);

       -- Populating the OUTPUT variable using the other variables that were passed
       -- for INSERT statement.

        SELECT @NewID = ID 
        FROM [Practice_DB].[dbo].[MY_EMPLOYEE]
        WHERE EMPID = @Emp_ID

        -- One row affected
        COMMIT TRANSACTION 
        RETURN 1
    END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END

        -- Rollback, no row affected
        RETURN 0
    END CATCH

END

GO
```

**Calling Stored Procedure**

```
DECLARE @value int, @ID VARCHAR(100)

EXECUTE @value =  usp_ProcName 
@Emp_ID = 50, 
@Name = 'John',
@LanguageID = 50,
@NewID = @ID OUTPUT  --<-- passing this variable with OUTPUT key word this will be 
                     -- populated inside the Procedure and then you can SELECT it or 
                     -- whatever you want to do with this value.  
SELECT @ID
SELECT @value
```

Comment: Encountering a problem here.  The [media_id] field gets automatically generated when inserting a record via sql.  So the EXECUTE statment isn't working for me because I don't need that parameter to insert.  Is there any other way to call it?

Comment: @javisrk Your are not passing any value to `@mediaid` , you are only passing a varible with KEY WORD `OUTPUT` to parameter @mediaid once the procedure is executed your passed variable get populated and you can select it do whatever you want to do with this variable, Not knowing much whats hapening inside your store procedure it hard for me to tell you exactly how you can populate your OUTPUT variable.

Comment: @javisrk I have Created a table and then a Stored Procedure for it which does pretty much everything what your Procedure should do have a closer look and hopefully this will clear any misunderstanding you have .

Answer (score 0):

This should help: [Return Data from a Stored Procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @return_value int
    DECLARE @media_id uniqueidentifier
    --get the value from the stored procedure here 
    Declare @SQL varchar(max)
    set @SQL='INSERT SQL STATEMENT HERE
    SELECT @media_id FROM [media] WHERE 1 = 1'
    exec @SQL

    -- One row affected
    RETURN 1
END TRY
```